# Undoing Git Clean

Tags: git

So I accidentally removed some new, untracked files from the working tree using `git clean -f`. Is there a way to undo the clean or re-add those untracked files?

Comment: No, there isn't. If they're untracked, Git has nothing to do with them. Don't do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your files were cleaned by Git, then they weren't tracked by Git int he first place. Unfortunately you're left with whatever other method you use to restore files from a backup.

This is not something that Git can help you with.

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood what they meant by "remove" here http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html. It sounded more like git clean stops tracking the files as opposed to deleting them outright.

Comment: @Tony If you want files to stop appearing in `git status`, the way to do that is to add them to your `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` files ([docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)).